# buffering location /tmp?

Tags: video, streaming

I was a long time Ubuntu user before I moved on to a Mac; so I'm used to seeing videos on YouTube and copying the buffered files from /tmp to another place for later viewing, if I like the video.

I tried doing the same on my Mac but its not working. Are the videos being buffered to a location other than /tmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use something like [Tooble](http://tooble.tv/) to watch videos and later download them in the format of your choice. It has a free and a pro version as far as I know. I use the free and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Likely they reside in the Application's Cache directory.

Look into `(HOME)/Library/Caches` and `(HOME)/Library/Application Support`